# PineScript Help - Backtesting Strategy "No Data", uknown error in logic

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

Backtesting Strategy "No Data" on any timeframe, uknown error in logic. Visually with the indicators there should be positions taken.

The issue occurred when I changed timeframe on RSI and SMA from chart to 720 (12HR) with the request.security function. Searched in here and in the pinescript docs and cant figure out the error.

Any help would be appreciated!

Script:

```
strategy('RSI Crossover Strategy', shorttitle='RSI Cross', default_qty_type=strategy.percent_of_equity, default_qty_value=5, initial_capital=1000, calc_on_every_tick=true)
// inputs
rsiLength = input(title='RSI Length', defval=14)
smaLength = input(title='SMA Length', defval=21)
// data/series
rsi = request.security(syminfo.ticker, "720", ta.rsi(close, rsiLength))
sma = request.security(syminfo.ticker,"720", ta.sma(rsi, smaLength))
ma = request.security(syminfo.ticker, "1D", ta.sma(close, 200))
// plot
plotColor = rsi > sma ? color.green : color.red
rsiPlot = plot(rsi, color=color.new(plotColor, 0), title='RSI')
smaPlot = plot(sma, color=color.new(color.white, 0), title='SMA')
fillColor = rsi > sma ? color.lime : color.red
fill(rsiPlot, smaPlot, color=color.new(fillColor, 75))
oversoldLine = hline(30, title='Oversold level')
overboughtLine = hline(70, title='Overbought level')
// strategy
buy = ta.crossover(rsi, sma) and rsi<44 
sell = ta.crossunder(rsi, sma) and rsi>50 and close<ma
TPL = ta.crossunder(rsi, sma) and rsi>55
TPS = ta.crossover(rsi, sma) and rsi<45

if ((ta.crossover(rsi, sma)) and (rsi<44))
    strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long, comment="Long")

if ((ta.crossunder(rsi, sma)) and (rsi>55))
    strategy.close("Long", comment="Close Long")

if ((ta.crossunder(rsi, sma)) and (rsi>50) and (close<ma))
    strategy.entry("Short",strategy.short, comment="Short")
   
if ((ta.crossover(rsi, sma)) and (rsi<45))
    strategy.close("Short", comment="Close Short")
```

Intent is to backtest a strategy with position entries and exits occuring when RSI and RSI SMA crossover and cross under on 12HR, executing on the 1HR close. 200D MA is to screen for short entry. I.e. no shorts if close is above 200D MA.

Comment: The code works fine and enter and exits trades. Consider changing the ticker you are using or change the logic to suit that specific ticker

Comment: I've rolled back your edit. It is not appropriate to edit a solution into the question. If you've solved the problem and want to share that solution, do so properly by writing an answer in the space provided for that purpose below. See [Can I answer my own question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) for more information.